# PHP MySQL - An attempt at recursive functions

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I'm trying out my first recursive function (at least I think I am!) and it only half works. First, the code:

```
function check_title($i,$title) {
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM posts WHERE Title = '$title'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
    if($num==0) {
            return $title;
    }else {
            $title=$title.' ('.$i++.')';
            check_title($i,$title);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is taking a string (title) and checking if that title exists in the db already. If it does, I want to append a number to the newer of the duplicates (e.g. 'I Am A Title' becomes 'I Am A Title-2'). I then need to run the function again to check this new version of my title, and increase the appended value as required ('I Am A Title-3'). Once no duplication is discovered, return the Title in its acceptable form.

It works when no duplication is found (the easy bit), but fails when duplication is found. Instead of appending a number, the entire title variable is emptied.

Any help would by greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a completely unnecessary use of recursion, and could just as easily accomplished with a basic loop.

Comment: Put return $title in the else block too, as thats where the call is made from.

Comment: It is? I thought that anything that would have to run for an indefinate number of cycles was ideal for a recursive function - am I wrong? Or how is this case unsuitable?

Comment: You also need to change `$i++` to `++$i` (pre-increment instead of post-increment)

Comment: @Eamonn Recursion has a few very specific use cases, tree traversal is a big one... a `while` loop is a basic loop that is ideal for a loop containing an undefined amount of iterations.

Comment: Why you are making recursive function? It' beneficiary to take count(title) than recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop instead...

```
$record_exists = true;
$title_base = "I Am A Title";
$title = $title_base;
$i = 0;
while($record_exists) {
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM posts WHERE Title = '$title'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
    if($num==0) {
        $record_exists = false;
        // Exit the loop.
    }
    else {
        $i++;
        $title = $title_base . "-" . $i;
    }
}

echo $title; // last existing title
```

However, **optimally you'd do more work with a single SQL query** and iterate the result, saving a lot of trips to and from the database.

**And just for fun...**

```
$title_base = "I Am A Title";
$title = $title_base;
for ($i=1, $num=1; $num != 0; $i++)
{
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM posts WHERE Title = '$title'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
    $title = $title_base . "-" . $i;
}

echo $title; // next title in sequence (doesn't yet exist in the db)
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's very helpful. But I'm curious now as to why everyone is saying recursion is not the answer - why wouldn't one use a recursive function here? Is it just a case of the simpler solution being the best?

Comment: Yes.  Occam's Razor is your friend in this field.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks again! Guess I was trying to be too clever for my own good :)

Comment: You're not alone, employing cleverness is satisfying, unfortunately it's not always to best solution.

Comment: @Eamonn: in procedural/object oriented language like PHP, recursion is rarely the only possible solution, while at the same time it introduces a risk of (gasp!) stack overflow. Generally it's good to avoid it, unless you really know you want it. On the other hand in functional languges like OCaml, recursion is one of the most basic tools, while usage of loops is very much limited.

Comment: @Mchl Yes, I must study them properly, from the ground up I think. I had seen them used elsewhere and thought they were a very efficient solution. Thx for the pointers.

Comment: Is there a possibility that some titles will be missing and need to be inserted? If not why not use mysql's COUNT() function as per my response and remove the necessity for both recursion and looping?#

Comment: @SOliver why are you advertising your answer as a comment on someone else's answer?

Comment: I realise that plugging responses isn't particularly gentlemanly but using a loop or recursive function in this sense is madness: say there 1000 matching titles, that's 1000 queries. Even selecting using all matching titles with LIKE or SUBSTR and iterating through the results would make more sense. In short it wasn't cool to make the plug but given the proposed solutions it appeared the sensible choice, in the same way folk are shunning the use of recursion; why iterate x times where iteration isn't required?

Comment: As I state in my answer, but my answer is simply explaining the recursion -> loop comparison, not sure a working solution deserves a downvote.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I'm wondering if you could adapt your second snippet to NOT mark the first iteration of a title, but only from the second one on? ('I Am A Title', 'I Am A Title-2', etc.) I messing around with it here, and, while I can work the first snippet no prob, the second is catching me out...

Comment: @jondavidjohn I might just be being over zealous with the ethos of the site but I feel a bad solution shouldn't be ranked highly; it might lead future readers to implement something similar. That said I appreciate you based your answer on Eamonn's question.

Answer (score 2):

As Mchl stated, the empty title is due to a lack of return in the else branch.

However, there is a problem with the function as it does not do what you intend. Currently, your function is building $title as 'Title-1-2-3-4-etc' the way you currently append the number to the title and check again. Instead of passing a modified title on the recursed call you should just pass the base title. Then, for the query, modify the title.

```
function check_title($title, $i = 0) {
    $qtitle = $title . ($i == 0 ? '' : "-$i");
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM posts WHERE Title = '$qtitle'");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($q);
    if($num==0) {
        return $title . ($i == 0 ? '' : "-$i");
    }else {
        return check_title(++$i,$title);
    }
}
```

PS, I also changed the order of parameters that way your initial call doesn't need to specify 0.

```
$title = check_title($title);
```

PPS, I should mention this is a solution to do it via recursion. However, a recursive solution is not the proper solution here as it needlessly makes return trips to the DB. Instead, you should use an sql query that selects all titles LIKE "$title%" Order by title asc. Then, iterate through each result and do a regex comparison with the title to see if it matches a pattern <title>|<title>-<#>. If it does you increment a duplicate counter. At the end you spit out the title with an appended counter value. I'll leave that solution as an exercise for the original poster.

Comment: I'm going with the loop as suggessted by jondavidjohn as being the best solution to my problem, but I appreciate seeing a working function as I was aiming for originally. I'll study this and see how these things are properly formulated, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

1. You lack a `return` in `else` branch.
2. Recursion is not the best idea for this application. <s>Hint: do a query like this `SELECT MAX(Title) FROM posts WHERE Title LIKE '$title%');`</s>

Comment: Your hint is bad, MAX() is not the right way to do this, e.g. 'A title-9' and 'A title-10'. 9 will win.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function is fine except for 2 things:

1. The original title isn't maintained between recursive calls. Hence each time `$title = $title . ' (' . $i++ . ')'` runs, another parenthesis is appended to the title, like "abc", "abc (1)", "abc (1) (2)" and so on.
2. You are returning $title when no more matches are found but no title is returned in the ELSE. It is important to do so. When the execution reaches the IF, it returns the title but the returned title is not assigned anywhere and hence is lost.

Here is the revised code:

```
$orgTitle = 'I am a title';
function check_title($i, $title = '') {
    global $orgTitle;
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM posts WHERE Title = '$title'");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($q);
    if ($num == 0) {
        return $title;
    } else {
        $title = $orgTitle . ' (' . ++$i .')';
        return check_title($i, $title);
    }
}
echo check_title(0, $orgTitle);
```

Note the addition of new variable $orgTitle. I've replaced it in the assignment statement inside the ELSE. This does the fix for point 1 above.

Also note the `return` added before `check_title` call in the ELSE. This solves point 2.

Hope it makes sense!

**Add-on**: Recursions are confusing, logically complex and tricky to debug. Also, recursive calls consume more memory (not in case of simple operations like your example) because the compiler/interpreter had to maintain the state variables for all steps in a recursion.

Comment: Upvoted for another example of a proper recursive function :)

Answer (score -1):

In order to minimise MySql interactions I'd recommend something similar to the following.

```
function checkTitle($title)
{
    /*Return all iterations of the title*/
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(title) AS titleCount FROM posts 
                    WHERE SUBSTR(title, 1,". strlen($title) .") = '$title' ");
    /*Return the incremented title*/
    return $title. (mysql_result($res, 0, "titleCount")  + 1);

}
```

Example:

```
mysql> select title from posts;
+----------+
| title    |
+----------+
| firefox1 |
| firefox2 |
| shoe     |
| firefox3 |
+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(title) AS titleCount FROM posts WHERE SUBSTR(title, 1,7) = 'firefox' ;
+------------+
| titleCount |
+------------+
|          3 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

---- Follow up test

```
Test table structure.
mysql>SHOW COLUMNS FROM posts;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| title | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

/*Test code and output*/
function checkTitle($title)
{
    /*Return all iterations of the title*/
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(title) AS titleCount FROM posts 
                    WHERE SUBSTR(title, 1,". strlen($title) .") = '$title' ");
    /*Return the incremented title*/
    return $title. (mysql_result($res, 0, "titleCount")  + 1);

}
mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password");
mysql_select_db("test");
echo checkTitle("firefox");

Output: firefox4
```

Comment: Its throwing 'not a valid result resource...' errors? Column and var names are correct...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I never bracketed up the decrement in SUBSTR() which probably passed an int instead of a string to mysql_query(). I've updated the code, please try it and let me know how you get on - ideally posting mysql_error() in response if it doesn't work.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,3)' at line 2

Comment: Sorry third time lucky: Missing comma in the SUBSTR() call, as I've commented I'm not in a position to construct a table and test the queries.

Comment: No change made to the returned title at all, and no errors thrown :/ Checked the Column and var names again.

Comment: Hmm, bear with me twenty minutes in the name of good practice I'll commandeer something with MySql on it.

Comment: Right; I've updated the query and posted an example of the sql in action.

Comment: Ok, tried in and it didnt work, so I put it directly into PHPMyAdmin (I have two posts called 'Test', I the var with the string 'Test'). Returned 0 rows? It must be something on my side - is there something I should check? `SELECT COUNT( Title ) AS titleCount
FROM posts
WHERE SUBSTR( Title, 1, ". strlen(Test) ." ) = 'Test'`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working at your end, poosibly the missing $ in strlen() - although that's more likely a typo in the post. I've updated my answer to show my full test method and output.